# ASP.NET : Hiding columns in gridview

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview

Is there a way I can control columns from code.

I had a drop drop box with select : Daily and weekend and the gridview column with Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday,sunday. 
If the user selects Daily i want to show columns only from Monday to Friday.

It is possible to control from the code. Oh i am using this griview in my webpage and coding  in done using C#.

help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.columns.aspx) property:

```
GridView1.Columns[5].Visible = false
GridView1.Columns[6].Visible = false
```

Answer (score 3):

All these code snippet only works when you have AutoGenerateColumns set to false. If you are using AutoGeneratedColumns then you have to loop each row and hide the appropiate cells.

Thank

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. All the other answers I've seen ignore that and this is an important distinction and your answer saved me some time.

Answer (score 1):

In the Item DataBound event handler sub, for every grid row, check the drop list for "Daily" or "weekend" and then set the visibility of the columns in question to False or true where appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically hide or reveal columns by indexing into the [Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.columns(VS.80).aspx) collection and setting the Visible property.

For example, to hide the first column in your gridview:

```
theGridview.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a hassle for you to use the index of the column -- conveniently, the Columns property also accepts the name of the column, which you can set on creation using the Name property of the column. This helps make the code self-documenting.

Comment: There is no name indexer on the Columns property, if there is, can you reference the MSDN doc?