# Updating only specific columns row in gridview programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a gridview and i bound it programmatically and doing the editing and updating programmatically also . I use this code to get updated value of a  cell

```
String d1 = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text;
```

For editing

```
 GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        GridView1.DataSource = Session["UserData"];
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

I use this .

But my question is  . When i click a row's edit button ,  i want to see update textbox field only last 4 cells of that row except first 2 cells .

How can i achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Hide the columns you don't want to see.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199832/asp-net-hiding-columns-in-gridview

Comment: I want to see that column but , dont' want to see update textbox behind it when i click edit.. is it possible

Comment: Can you post your `GridView` definition?